# The right way to talk about my thesis?

Tags: grammaticality, phrase-requests

Is either of these grammatically and semantically correct?

> As part of my undergraduate thesis, I undertook a project under ...

or

> I undertook a thesis research project under ...

If not, how do I phrase it such that it indicates I took up a project **and** submitted a thesis on the subject?

Comment: I think the second one because it is a title or topic of thesis .

Comment: the word "under" is used in a few words in your sentence, this confounds the matter a little

Comment: @NewAlexandria `under Prof. XYZ at ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean to say: 'As part of my undergraduate degree/course, I undertook a project, on which I submitted a thesis'?

I am a UK person and this reflects what might be the case here.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I meant to say; but is there a better way to put that? The project description comes after "undertook a project" and the last fragment which says I submitted a thesis seems out of place. :(

Comment: How about: 'I undertook a project on the subject of the influence of homeopathy on mainstream medicine; that being the subject of my thesis'?

Comment: I think it is better to have 2 separate sentences. How does " I presented my findings in my undergraduate thesis" sound? Is it correct?

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

I submitted a thesis on (topic) as a part of my undergraduate project.

Comment: I have an explanation of the project that follows. "I submitted a thesis on..." doesn't seem like something I can expand on.

Comment: You could follow it with, "PROJECT SUMMARY:" or a similar title and proceed with the actual summation.